# Are there resources for original recipes in Shokugeki no Soma?

Tags: shokugeki-no-soma

*Shokugeki no Soma* has hell ton of dishes, and in the anime at least, they all look freaking tasty. Now I understand that there is a difference between anime and reality and due to which, taste and look differs. I also found on internet, that the mangaka of *Shokugeki no Soma* uses assistance of a pro chef while writing stories.

There are tons of videos on YouTube trying to replicate the dishes, but most of them change the recipe or something while cooking the dish.

Are there videos or pages on the internet where they have **exact recipe and same method used in the anime/manga**?

Comment: AFAIK, being a "fantasy cooking" manga/anime, I guess the first question would be: is it possible to replicate the technique/recipe in the first place...

Comment: Well, if writer went through the pain of consulting a professional chef, they must be..... I guess.

Comment: I have done a quick research in Japanese, but there doesn't seem any other sources for official recipes other than those listed in the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the manga has recipe pages after each section - however I don't think there is anywhere they are all compiled, as a recipe book.

Disclaimer: I don't read the series, I've just seen pages like this on Pinterest. It may be they are only in the serialization comics.

Example:

[image]

This is a reasonably common practice with cooking manga, I definetly have a few different books at home that have recipes from the story in them :)